# How to get common attributes from object array in mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

Below is the sample document

```
[
  {
    "name": "john"
    "attribute":[
        {
            nameAttr: "abc"
            tagAttr: "zxs"
            
        },
        {
            nameAttr: "asd"
            tagAttr: "zxs"
            
        },
        {
            nameAttr: "lll"
            tagAttr: "zxs"
            
        },
        ]
  },
  {
    "name": "john"
    "attribute":[
        {
            nameAttr: "abc"
            tagAttr: "zxs"
            
        },
        {
            nameAttr: "sss"
            tagAttr: "zxs"
            
        },
        {
            nameAttr: "asd"
            tagAttr: "zxs"
            
        },
        ]
  },
]
```

I want to get all common nameAttr output as ["abc","asd"] as they are common in both document
I am able to project only nameAttr with project but dont know how to proceed further
db.collection.aggregate([

```
{
    $project: {
      "attribute.nameAttr": 1,
      
    }
  }
])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) to collect all attribute names into an array of arrays and then use [$reduce](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/index.html) with [$setIntersection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setIntersection/index.html) to get the common ones:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: null,
            attributes: { $push: "$attribute.nameAttr" }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            commonAttributes: {
                $reduce: {
                    input: "$attributes",
                    initialValue: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$attributes", 0 ] },
                    in: { $setIntersection: [ "$$value", "$$this" ] }
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/TOwTEG1Ur6x)